# Overstay in Germany

Tags: netherlands, schengen, overstay

I arrived at Bochum Germany in Aug on a **Intra-Corporate Transfer** (ICT) visa and I did request for an appointment regarding the residence permit for which I have also sent the documents.

I did not receive any updates regarding my application until now.

Due to an unavoidable situation I have to travel back to India but in the airport I was stopped at immigration and asked for RP. Since I did not receive, the authorities charged an offense letter. I explained them about the situation but they said Visa office in Bochum will decide. I have resigned my job with the current organization and I'm expected to join another employer in Netherlands from Jan 2022.

I'm more worried that what if I get a ban from entering any Schengen Zone. Can someone please let me know will this affect my Netherlands visa or will I be stopped at the Netherlands immigration when I travel to The Netherlands.

Comment: Thank you for the response. There is a portal where you are suppose to request for appointment when I submitted that on September there was just a message on browser your request will take lot of time process. There was no confirmation email. How can I ensure my request has reached the foreign office?

Answer (score 2):

> I did request for an appointment regarding the residence permit for which I have also sent the documents.
> ...
> , the authorities charged an offense letter. I explained them about the situation but they said Visa office in Bochum will decide.

The charge will probably be dropped by the Immigration Office in Bochum, since they will see that you made an appointment and submitted the required documents (thus fulfilling all obligations).

Since you have permanently left Germany, your case will be closed and noted in the Visa Information System (VIS). This should not lead to any ban.

The Netherlands will see the previous case, but it should have no effect on the new application with the new employer.

Comment: @Murali Write a letter (no longer employed at that firm ; have left Germany permanently ; request confirmation of letter) with reference to offense letter (which I assume you have a copy of) to the immigration office in Bochum.